# ZooKeeper gives exiting JVM with error code 2 error

Tags: jvm, apache-zookeeper

I have openjdk16.0.1, zookeper and kafka in my machine.

When I use the command "zkServer.cmd start" it gives me the error below.

```
ERROR [main:QuorumPeerMain@99] - Invalid config, exiting abnormally
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing C:\Users\****\Desktop\apache-zookeeper-3.7.0-bin\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:198)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:125)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
        at java.base/java.util.Properties.loadConvert(Properties.java:672)
        at java.base/java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:456)
        at java.base/java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:408)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:185)
        ... 2 more
Invalid config, exiting abnormally
2021-04-30 17:25:17,422 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZKAuditProvider@42] - ZooKeeper audit is disabled.
2021-04-30 17:25:17,428 [myid:] - ERROR [main:ServiceUtils@42] - Exiting JVM with code 2
```

Is there any solution for this?

```
tickTime=2000 
initLimit=10 
syncLimit=5 
dataDir=C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\apache-zookeeper-3.7.0-bin\data clientPort=2181
```

Now I changed the place of the zookeper folder. it is now under C:
dataDir=C:\apache-zookeeper-3.7.0-bin\data
However, there is still and error. This time:

```
ERROR [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@70] - Invalid arguments, exiting abnormally
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C:\apache-zookeeper-3.7.0-bin\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:660)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:778)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerConfig.parse(ServerConfig.java:78)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:110)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:68)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:141)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:91)
```

Comment: For starters, look into the `C:\Users\****\Desktop\apache-zookeeper-3.7.0-bin\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg` file whether you can find malformed \uxxxx sequences.

Comment: @Holger zoo.cfg is like below (other lines have # in front of them):
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\apache-zookeeper-3.7.0-bin\data
clientPort=2181

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include information. But note that there *is* a `\U` in that line… It’s a bit strange, as it is an uppercase u that should not get interpreted as `\uxxxx`, but [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-) makes it pretty clear that backslash sequences are interpreted, so you must escape literal backslash characters with another backslash.

Comment: @Holger I tried to put \\ for U and u. My user name also starts with \u. but when I put the escape character nothing changes

Comment: I also changed the file location, and the error type changed.

Comment: You have to escape *all* backslashes. The linked documentation says “*The method does not treat a backslash character, \, before a non-valid escape character as an error; the backslash is silently dropped.*” So not escaping a backslash character will either lead to an unintended sequence (when forming a valid sequence by chance) or get dropped silently. In either case, the result is not what you want.

Comment: @Holger I solved that one now by your help, but now I have another problem with  java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67). you can see the new error at the topic. I edited it

Comment: Since the exception happens `at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerConfig.parse(ServerConfig.java:78)` it’s worth looking at [that code location](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/server/ServerConfig.java#L78), to see that this method passes its first string argument to `parseInt` to get the port number. You just have to go up the stack trace to check the origin of that array, though I suspect that it will come directly from the command line. But it shouldn’t be too hard to verify the four caller locations…

Comment: I have nothing to check the stack trace. I havent got exlipse. I will just run my python script through the Kafka server and first of all I need to start the zookeper server.

Comment: You don’t need Eclipse. I already provided a link to the starting point. The next two are easy to find nearby, [`initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:110)`](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/server/ZooKeeperServerMain.java#L110) and [`ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:68)`](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/server/ZooKeeperServerMain.java#L68). They pass-through the argument(s) as suspected.

Comment: Then, look at [`QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:141)`](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/server/quorum/QuorumPeerMain.java#L141) and [`QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:91)`](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/server/quorum/QuorumPeerMain.java#L91) and you’ll find, it’s truly the first argument from the command line that ended up at `Integer.parseInt`. Study the entire `QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun` and you’ll recognize what went wrong…

Comment: Thanks @Holger, previously I was typing zKserver.cmd start from the console, currently I am just typing zKserver and it works